# Watch apple tv on someone else's device

Tags: family-sharing, home-sharing, tv.app

I purchased some media content (not a subscription) in the Apple TV app, using my iPhone. Is there any way I can watch this content on my family member's iPad?

(Note, we have already set up family sharing for iCloud, and I'm not the "family organiser".)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you and the family member who has the iPad are both part of the same Apple Family.

1. On your family member's device, open the TV app.
2. Tap the library icon on the upper-left side to open the library.
3. Tap 'Family Sharing'.
4. Tap your name to display all the Apple content you've purchased.
5. Tap the download button to download and watch the content.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201085).